# Grand Central Dispatch. How Do I Query a Queue to see if it is in use?

Tags: ios5, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

What is the best/simplest way to detect if a queue I have created is currently in use? My intent here is to defer a particular action until all queued tasks have completed.

Thanks,
Doug

### UPDATE

Here is a bit more context. I have an async serial queue (private dispatch queue) that is a property of my object. When this queue completes its work it calls `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {...})` to up date the UI. Currently the app runs only in landscape interface orientation. I am now adding support for both portrait & landscape interface orientation. For now, I prefer not to allow the interface to rotate to/from portrait/landscape while my GCD async task is running. So in my controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method I want to return `NO` during those periods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct support for that in GCD.  You can probably get the effect you're looking for in other ways, though.

- Do you just want to run a block after other blocks have completed? Put the blocks in a `dispatch_group`, and submit your "after everything's done action" using `dispatch_group_notify`. This works with concurrent or sequential queues.
- Similarly, put your blocks in a group, and call `dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)`. If it returns non-zero, then there are outstanding blocks in the group.
- Is your queue sequential, and you want to wait until the other blocks have completed, blocking the current thread until then? Just issue your handler using `dispatch_sync` on the same queue.

There are other possibilities, depending on your exact situation.

**Edit:** Based on your update, there's an even easier way:

- add a `BOOL` property to your view controller, called `allowsOrientationChange`
- override `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to return `self.allowsOrientationChange`
- at the start of your work block, do a `dispatch_async` to set the property to NO
- at the end of your work block, do a `dispatch_async` to set the property to YES

(There's a little bit of a race condition between when the property is set to NO on the main thread, and when the rest of your work happens in the queue. You could make it a `dispatch_sync` if that really matters. Depends on what your reasons are for preventing rotation, I suppose.)

Comment: yes. I like this approach very much. Thanks very much for this. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in control of all the tasks going into the queue whose completion you care about, you can use the [dispatch group APIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25) to group them together and get notified when they complete. If you aren't using a queue whose tasks you're completely in control of, you can roll your own notification by queueing a block whose sole purpose is to generate such a notification (though this really only applies if you're using a serial queue).